# Having Trouble Adding Select Options from JSON data

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a list of items for a drop down list using a jQuery ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PCSI.aspx/GetIndividuals",
    data: '{role: "' + $('#ddlRole').value + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        alert(data.d);
        $('#ddlIndividuals').find('option').remove().end();
        $("#ddlIndividuals").append($("<option></option>").text('<All>')
                                                         .val(-1));
        $.each(data.d, function(index, item) {
        $("#ddlIndividuals").append(
                           $("<option></option>").text(item.Display)
                                                         .val(item.Value));
        });
    }
});
```

The alert(data.d) tells me that my data looks good:

```
[{"Display":"test","Value":"1"},{"Display":"test2","Value":"2"}]
```

But the $.each does not seem to be working. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm getting Display is null or not an object.

Comment: I think the response content type is not set properly. I have a ScriptMethod attribute with ResponseFormat = JSON. I thought that would work.

Answer (score 0):

even though its long time this question has been posted, I am answering it now, anybody might get help from it in future.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PCSI.aspx/GetIndividuals",
  data: '{role: "' + $('#ddlRole').value + '"}',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data, textStatus) {
    alert(data.d);
    $('#ddlIndividuals').empty().append($("<option><All></option>").val(-1));
    $.each(data.d, function(index, item) {
      var opt = $("<option>"+item["Display"]+"</option>").val(item["Value"]);
      $("#ddlIndividuals").append(opt);
    });
  }
});
```

I have used `empty()` instead of `remove()` and `end()`.